# Wildfly 10 with JVM 8 hung when gc log rotate

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, wildfly-10

I'm using solaris 10, java 1.8.0_66, Wildfly 10.0.Final. And I set the GC options to be the following:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -verbosegc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=30 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xloggc:/mylocation/standalone/log/gc.log"
```

I let Wildfly run for a few days, finally gc log file reached to 1M. when rotating, the gc log file was renamed to be gc.log.0, and gc.log.1.current was created with size 0. after that all the log files seemed no activities any more. server.log file has no change, gc.log.1.current has no change,  I couldn't access Wildfly via port 8080 any more. Wildfly java process hung at that time. 
I then collected 3 jstack for wildfly java process with 1 minute interval, they are exactly the same, this means java process really hung.

Does anyone know any issues related to gc log file rotating in java 8?

Thanks, Helen

Comment: Attach with jvisualvm and figure out what is going on in the JVM.  You may also want to start the Wildfly JVM in debug mode so you can attach with a debugger to investigate more.

Comment: It is also recommended to use latest version 1.8.0_121

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn, if I attache jvisualvm, what specific areas I should watch, like thread, memory, to monitor this issue?  from jstack, I found the majority of the threads are in BLOCK state.

Comment: Hi Fairoz, I'll try latest version. I did some more testing on this, I found when no one is using the system, system is not busy, when gc log file rotate, the java process actually freeze for about 4 minutes, and then the system back to work. So it is not like jvm crashed, it is just jvm freeze at the time when gc log rotates.  I can imagine when in production the freezing time would be longer.  Do you have any idea why?